# Elixir: Trying to Write a Map to CSV, Being Written as Stream Results

Tags: csv, stream, elixir

I've been scratching my head on this one for a while. I am trying to write a program which outputs the frequency of every word in a given text file to a .csv file. I have succeeded in creating functions that find the frequency of each word and output the result of this as a map, but my tocsv function writes the results as Stream results for some reason and I cannot figure out why, or how to avoid this. Here is my code:

```
defmodule WordFrequency do

  def wordCount(readFile) do
     readFile
     |> words
     |> count
     |> tocsv
  end

  defp words(file) do
    file
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing(&1))
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1,~r{[^A-Za-z0-9_]}))
    |> Enum.to_list
    |> List.flatten

  end

  defp count(words) when is_list(words) do
    Enum.reduce(words, %{}, &update_count/2)
  end

  defp update_count(word, acc) do
    Map.update acc, String.to_atom(word), 1, &(&1 + 1)
  end

  defp tocsv(map) do
    file = File.open!("test.csv", [:write, :utf8])
    map
    |> IO.inspect
    |> Enum.map(&CSV.encode(&1))
    |> Enum.each(&IO.inspect(file, &1, []))
  end

end
```

The results of count (it's a test file) are:

```
bitterness: 1, fan: 1, respiration: 1, radiator: 1, ceiling: 1, run: 1,
  duck: 1, roundess: 1, terrorism: 1, she: 1, over: 1, equipment: 2, test: 1,
  freshness: 1, feminism: 1, bucket: 1, goodness: 1, manliness: 1,
  reflection: 1, uncomfortable: 1, tourism: 1, house: 1, ableism: 1, stairs: 1,
  heroism: 1, sadness: 1, socialism: 1, fruit: 1, dogs: 1, mechanism: 1,
  symbolism: 1, predilection: 1, up: 1, sedition: 1, faithfulness: 1,
  fruition: 1, criticism: 1, conformation: 1, extradition: 1, braveness: 1,
  ionization: 1, indigestion: 1, bubble: 1, introspection: 1, liquid: 1,
  apartment: 1, deep: 1, department: 1, centralization: 1, bitter: 1, ...}
```

So I know that I'm not passing a stream to my tocsv function, but something happens in tocsv that converts it to a stream and doesn't convert it to a writeable format before outputting to the csv file. Anyone have any idea how I can make a workaround to this? I am using this CSV module: https://github.com/beatrichartz/csv

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an example of producing the CSV in the `README` of the `CSV` module you use:

```
file = File.open!("test.csv", [:write, :utf8])
table_data |> CSV.encode |> Enum.each(&IO.write(file, &1))
```

Please note, that [`IO.write/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#write/2) writes the bytes to the device, while [`IO.inspect/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/3) *inspects the second argument according to the given options using the `IO` device*. Also, `CSV.encode/1` expects a **two-dimensional list**.

That said, you probably should stick with `IO.write/2` as mentioned in the example, and produce a 2d list in `count` rather that a `Map`:

```
defp count(words) when is_list(words) do
  words
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, &update_count/2)
  |> Enum.reduce([], fn {k, v}, acc -> [[k, v] | acc] end)
end

defp tocsv(map) do
  file = File.open!("test.csv", [:write, :utf8])

  map
  |> IO.inspect
  |> CSV.encode
  |> Enum.each(&IO.write(file, &1))
end
```

---

In such an simple case, I would just use bare *Elixir* to produce a file, though (assuming `count` returns a map, as in your original code):

```
defp tocsv(map) do
  File.open("test.csv", [:write, :utf8], fn(file) ->
    Enum.each(map, &IO.write(file, Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(&1), ?,) <> "\n"))
  end)
end
```

---

Or, even simpler:

```
defp tocsv(map) do
  File.write!("test.csv", 
     map
     |> Enum.map(Enum.join(&Tuple.to_list(&1), ?,))
     |> Enum.join("\n"))
end
```

Comment: Hey, this is working great! I actually didn't realize Elixir alone could write to csv - This is an ideal and far simper solution. One issue I am having though,  is that the csv file produced just has all the data concantenated together without any breaks, like this:

organism1run1ceiling1plagiarism1taking1test1sounds1sadness1freshness1deep1stairs1conformation1investment2

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the csv to be formatted so each word, and its frequency, occurs on one line, with a tab or comma delineating the word from the frequency

Comment: Please see an update. [`Enum.join/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#join/2) has an option to specify `joiner` as second parameter, and the result is concatenated with `"\n"` now.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I figured this out by modifying the tocsv function like so:
'  defp tocsv(map) do
    File.open("test.csv", [:write, :utf8], fn(file) ->
      Enum.each(map, &IO.write(file, Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(&1), ", ")<>"\n"))
    end)
  end'

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But does this code also escape commas that could be found in the data? It seems to me it is the difference between the CSV package and plain Elixir.

Comment: @bortzmeyer no it obviously does not because in this particular case it’s not needed.